# How to assign headers in axios.all method React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm getting data from multiple api's and rendering into `<Pickers />` but the issue is that I'm unable to assign headers for Auth in this `axios.all` method. Kindly provide me a solution or mistake if I'm doing.

```
axios.all([
        axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/case/GetCaseType'),
        axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/case/GetCasePriority')
    ], { headers: { 'authorization': 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
        .then(axios.spread(( response2, response3) => {
            console.log('Response 1: ', response1.data.retrn);
            console.log('Response 2: ', response2.data.retrn);
            console.log('Response 3: ', response3.data.retrn);
            this.hideLoader();
        })).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

Comment: this can be made more neat and readable using `async/await` and `destructuring`, plus setting common things like `url, headers` as a config.

Comment: @its4zahoor can you make a example code for me eg: what it should be like

Comment: okay, i'm editing my answer to make this neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configs and create instance to set common things like `url, token, timeout` etc

```
import axios from 'axios';
const http = axios.create({
      baseURL: this.url,
      timeout: 5000
});

http.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = `bearer ${this.state.jwtToken}`

export async function yourAPIcallMethod(){
   try{
       const [res1,res2] = await http.all([getOneThing(), getOtherThing()]);
       //when all responses arrive then below will run
       //res1.data and res2.data will have your returned data
       console.log(res1.data, res2.data)
       //i will simply return them
       return {One: res1.data, Two: res2.data}
      }
   catch(error){
      console.error(error.message || "your message")
      }
}
```

This can be used in your component.jsx like

```
import {yourAPIcallMethod} from './httpService';

async componentDidMount(){
    const data = await yourAPIcallMethod();
    this.setState({One: data.One, Two: data.Two})
}
```

You can see and learn more on [github axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#config-defaults).

Comment: is this method apply on all service in this page?

Comment: this sets it on axios, so every axios call will have this header.

Comment: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_axios.default.defaults.common.headers')]
* src\screens\AddCaseScreen.js:101:30 in componentDidMount$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- ... 13 more stack frames from framework internals
`

Comment: you have put `default.defaults` instead of simply using `defaults`.

Comment: no, my code is `axios.defaults.common.headers['authorization'] = `bearer ${this.state.jwtToken}``

Comment: you have not used template literal in assignment correctly. should be = `\`bearer ${this.state.jwtToken}\``

Comment: it is same like that

Comment: sorry, i realized it's `headers.common`, earlier i used the opposite. Fixed in edit

Comment: so that will work only for these three services, what if I want to call other services using this file.  I mean if I want to create one file for all get services so what about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203877/discussion-between-its4zahoor-and-zain-khan).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service file to handle all request for  GET or POST, FIle for handling GET request with Autherization header is given belwo

GetService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let constant = {
    baseurl:'https://www.sampleurl.com/'
};
let config = {    
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const GetService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    // jwtKey is null then get request will be send without header, ie for public urls
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+jwtKey;
    }

    try{
        return axios.get(
                            constant.baseUrl+'api/'+Path, 
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to call all services together and I want to hide loader when all services are loaded.