# How to call multiple services in axios with header react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm calling almost 7 services in my component, they way I'm calling is mentioned below. Now I want that there should be a good and proper way for this. Right now I'm facing the issue is like if any one service loaded earlier so the loaded service hide he loader and screen stuck for 5 to 6 seconds because of other services loading. Please provide me a good solution for it. Thanks in advance

```
     componentDidMount() {
         this.showLoader();
          // service 1
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/service1para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   // service 2
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + 'serivce2para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   // service 3
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + 'serivce3para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   // service 4
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + 'serivce4para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   // service 5
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + 'serivce5para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   // service 6
          axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/serivce6para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
                        this.hideLoader();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
```

Comment: Do you really need all that info in the componentDidMount?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign headers in axios.all method React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243785/how-to-assign-headers-in-axios-all-method-react-native)

Comment: no @SuleymanSah this answer not works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical solution for this is to use `Promise.all` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all)).

It takes an array of promises and returns a promise that :

- resolves the list of resolved values once all promises in the array are resolved
- rejects if any one of the promises rejects

So it would be something like this :

```
  this.showLoader();
  Pomise.all([
    axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/service1para',
              {headers:{Authorization:'bearer '+this.state.jwtToken}})
         .then((response) => {
             this.setState({ clients: response.data.retrn });
             return Promise.resolve(response) // then it goes into the 'reponses' array below
         })
         .catch(err => console.log(err));),

    axios.get(/* ... */), // same thing over again

    /* ... */
  ])
  .then((responses) => {
    // here, responses[0] is the response of the first axios.get
    // response[1] is the response of the second axios.get, etc ..., if needed
    this.hideLoader()
  })
```

Comment: and how to pass auth headers?

Comment: the code in the axios.get( ... ) doesn't change (except for hideLoader that goes below)

Comment: how can I got the response data?

Comment: Yes that's a good, point. You need to make sure that each 'then' for each 'axios.get' returns a promise. So it would be 'return Promise.resolve(response)'. And then it is available in an array as first argument of the very last 'then'. I update my answer.

Comment: But you don't need this if you just do a setState with the response.

Comment: Ok so then it would be a setState in the last '.then' with the array 'responses'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios.all` to resolve all the promises and then when it is resolved you can clear the loader something like:

```
axios.all([
    axios.get(this.apiUrl + '/service1para', { headers: { Authorization: 'bearer ' + this.state.jwtToken } }),
    //all the other urls here
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((FirstRequestresponse, secondRequestResponse) => {
    //do whatever you want with both responses
    //you can now clear the loader
  })).catch(() =>{
    //you can clear the loader as well 
  }) ;
```